# Mechanism to shadow a void* pointer with a macro

Tags: c++

I noticed that I can speed up compile times (significantly) by hiding complicated objects as `void*` pointers in my class, and dealing with them in a isolated cpp. Forward declaring these classes is too hard to maintain.

Using a macro sometimes works, but sometimes it doesn't. Does anybody know of a way to shadow a variable with a cast so that I can get `l-value`? Is there something I can do with a structure that has an implicit cast operator that can give me an `l-value`. Is there some paradigmatic way to handle these problems that I'm not seeing?

```
struct K : CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel {};
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_triangulation_2<K> Triangulation;
typedef Triangulation::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
#define Triangulation_Ptr (static_cast<Triangulation*>(this->Triangulation_Ptr))
void MyClass::cleanTriangulation()
{
    delete Triangulation_Ptr;//works, this->Triangulation_Ptr is a void*
}
void MyClass::addToTriangulation(int idx, MyPoint l)
{
    if (Triangulation_Ptr == nullptr)
    {
        Triangulation_Ptr = new Triangulation;// No a l-value, doesn't compile
    }
    //something, that adds a point
}
```

Comment: Doesn't better type-safety (more correct type information) improve run-time performance?

Comment: I'm not sure what the maintenance headache is for forward declarations.

Comment: @PengZhang Doesn't matter because the compiler sees the correct structure information when we cast (or else it couldn't compile).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thats a good question, but at the end of the day a `void*` is easier to maintain then the inserting several lines of `typedefs` and manually writing out the namespace. If this works, everything would be good.

Comment: `void *` requires casts, that are not type-safe. The "easier to maintain" you are talking about is just the initial authoring of the code. It misses the picture of tracking down the weird bug that was caused by an erroneous cast that is almost impossible to find without major surgery. Not to mention you are just trading the "several lines of `typedefs`" with several lines of macros.

Comment: Sooner or later you're going to do something stupid, like put a `Base *` pointer in that `void *`, and later retrieve it as a `Derived *`.  If the `void *` pointers point to some specific type, just bite the bullet, put in the forward declarations, and use that type.

Comment: The fact that you write `//works` at the `delete` expression convinces me that this is an absolutely terrible idea.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah but I think it still calls the destructor, so it should work?

Comment: How long does your build take?  Is trading program correctness, run-time safety and maintainability worth the few seconds you gain from speeding up the build process with these changes?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I don't see a loss in maintainability or any of the other items. Everything is controlled by the `#define` which would be easier then controlling it in a few places. All be it this doesn't work, and I'm going to try to cook something up with a structure at a slightly later time.

Comment: @Mikhail: Have you asked your compiler? Or are warnings slowing down your build process too much, too?

Answer (score 1):

You will get a lot of people suggesting you don't do this, but I share your pain. Quite apart from compile times, the careful design and use of a layer of typedefs, templates and even macros can produce code in which the business logic is far easier to understand, even if the underlying code is not. You leave yourself open to occasional weird compile errors, but in my view the effort is worth it in carefully chosen situations.

Having said that, what you are trying to is not necessarily easy to achieve. If you're going to use macros, you want to flag them in a way that those who use them know what they're playing with.

Does something like this work?

#define Triangulation_Ptr *(Triangulation**)(&this->Triangulation_Ptr)

Part of the problem is that these are pointer-to-member, which are really not the same as ordinary pointers.